# How to execute clojure function with no arguments

Tags: clojure, lighttable

I have a clojure function defined which takes no arguments.

example

```
(defn m
[]
...)
```

How do I execute this function in light table..

`(m)` or`(m nil)` or anyway.

using `(m)` and `(m nil)` I didn't get any output

Comment: Share the actual function and it might be clearer why you're not seeing any output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To run that function you first need to evaluate the function definition – hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>  with the cursor on any of the lines of the function definition. Then you should be able to evaluate a line with code that calls your function, i.e. `(m)`.

When you evaluate Clojure code Light Table needs to connect to your code's Leiningen project (if you have one), it may connect to "LightTable-REPL" if there isn't one, or you can tell it to connect to the "Light Table UI" instead (if you want to play with Light Tables's code inside of LT itself).

It's also possible that your function doesn't have a return value, like if it only calls other functions (e.g. `print`) that are intended to have side effects but not a useful return value. But even in that case you should see `nil` printed in your Clojure file when you evaluate the line containing your function call.

If you're still having trouble, feel free
to ask for help in [the Light Table Gitter room](https://gitter.im/LightTable/LightTable), [the Google Groups group](https://groups.google.com/forum/m/#!forum/light-table-discussion), or, if you think you've found a bug, [open an issue on GitHub](https://github.com/LightTable/LightTable/issues/new).

Answer (score 7):

to run a function with no arguments the call looks like this:

```
(m)
```

if you added a nil it would be calling a function with one argument, and that argument would have the value `nil`. If you are not seeing output, then it's because your function does not produce any output. Since you are using light table make sure the call is at the top level and not inside another function definition (recount the `()`s)

Answer (score 2):

There are two modes for getting LightTable to perform Clojure:

1. In an instarepl, everything you type is instantly evaluated.
2. In a `.clj` file, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> evaluates the current context, and
   <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> evaluates the whole file.

In either case, you see what the expression evaluates to: *all* clojure expressions evaluate to something (if they don't throw an exception, also shown).

So I think you're using mode (2), *without evaluating the expression*.

Having said that, if you type enough nonsense, LightTable may give up on it.

If I'm right, you'll soon find out how to call a function without arguments.